# How is it possible that I can log into my account with two different passwords?

Tags: passwords, ubuntu-9.10

I just logged into my Linux machine on the account `ender` on two passwords. Both passwords work! How is it possible?

I'm using latest Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: Do you see something in `/var/log/auth.log` about both of them? What does it say?

Comment: What is account 'ender' ?  
What were the two passwords (if we can know) -- otherwise, how different are they, what are the md5 like?  
From where did you log on (tty, vty, sty, su, su - .... ) ?
What's the line like in /etc/shadow ?

Comment: Ender has sudoer ALL. I logged in from Putty, simple.  The line is like this (with letters changed) ....   ender:7.P22C5bQli72:14549:0:99999:7:::

Comment: So you logged in via SSH ? What kind of authentication scheme are you using for SSH ? Maybe it allows incoming connections from your username at your local IP ? SSH authentication isn't a topic I know very well, I prefer locking it down more than opening it up.

Comment: Yep, it's SSH. Other passwords don't work. just those 2 :)

Comment: Now it's time to follow Raphink's path - what's up with /var/log/auth.log ?

Comment: Maybe passwordless login  is enabled ? http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/bit/nopassword.html

Comment: Have you tried typing both passwords into notepad or a text editor to make sure they're actually coming out different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are both passwords more than 8 characters long? Some password backends respect only the first 8 characters of a password...

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about that! I wonder if Ubuntu's SSH server is old enough to fizzle there.

Comment: It is not the SSH server but rather the hash function used.

Comment: Yes,they're both more than 8 characters, and they both start with the same 8 characters.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I tried other passwords that start with the same 8 chars, and it works.

Comment: Hah. I did that once with Solaris...I thought I was being SO secure, and it turned out that my hilariously long 32 character password was only 8 characters long.